# Is there any plugin or feature that determines which JARs are unused in an application or a project (in a given project life cycle)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin

A typical Java project has 30-40 jar files. Maven resolves dependencies. Sometimes some features are no longer needed. But no one touches the JARs with the fear of breaking the code or application.

For example: jersey (JAX-RS) implementation with JAXB has many workarounds, different Maven configurations.

Different developers sometimes employ different methods to do the same thing. All are correct. I agree they should discuss out. But the problem is that unused JARs make the build package heavy.

Isn't there a plugin which can map (use reflection) and check for one time (one project life cycle) and mark unwanted or unused JARs. This will use java reflection and may get slow but this is needed.
Any solutions?

Comment: I must disagree vehemently with the statement that a typical Java project has 30 to 40 jar files.  A project with that many jars is either huge, or the developers are very sloppy about managing its dependencies.  The fact that Maven's dependency tree pulls in so many jars transitively does not absolve developers of this responsibility, in my opinion.  I've worked on many sizable Java EE projects with fewer than ten jars.

Comment: @VGR nice that you have worked with a project with less than 10 jars. But putting a number to the jars is something baseless. Spring, hibernate, junit, logging itself make up like 7-8. Do we use only this much, reporting, UI customization and what not is needed in projects. When a team size grows and if the team is located in multiple locations, the situation highlighted does occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven helps to find out unused dependencies with dependency plugin.

```
mvn dependency:analyze
```

its displays the unused dependencies as follow

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze (default-cli) @ mymaven ---
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.0:compile
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not that well versed with maven. This helped a lot. It helped me remove and organize the dependencies.